# JupyterLab - Folder Shortcuts

Tags: directory, shortcut, jupyter-lab, shortcut-file

Hey does anyone know if there is a handy way to create folder shortcuts, or quickly navigate between folders in JupyterLab? Unfortunately my files are spread over a SharePoint site and im trying to figure out the most efficient way to fire up my notebooks.

Cheers

searched through jupyerlab settings, google search etc.

Comment: https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyterlab-favorites ?

Comment: Yep there’s a couple of extensions for favorite folders/files. I kept thinking/searching for shortcuts when it should have been favorite. Thanks

Comment: There is also https://github.com/parente/jupyterlab-quickopen